# C++ ostream char**

Tags: c++, ostream

I built a class `Client`, and I want to get `ostream` of it. This is the class:

```
class Client {
    MyString id;
    MyString full_name;
    char gender;
    unsigned short age;
    unsigned short hobbies_num;
    char** hobbies_list;
```

and here is the piece of code i already wrote:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osc, const Client& for_print)
{
    return osc << for_print.id << endl << for_print.full_name << endl << for_print.gender << endl << for_print.age << endl << for_print.hobbies_num << endl;
}
```

My question is how can I print the last member, `hobbies_list`, which is 2-dimension dynamical array of chars?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char**`.

Comment: I agree with the above: why complicating things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < for_print.hobbies_num; i++) {
    osc << for_print.hobbies_list[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use standard algorithm `std::for_each`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& osc, const Client& for_print)
{
    osc << for_print.id << endl << for_print.full_name << endl << for_print.gender << endl << for_print.age << endl << for_print.hobbies_num << endl;
    for_each(for_print.hobbies_list, for_print.hobbies_list + for_print.hobbies_num, [&](char* x){osc << x << endl; });
    return osc; 
}
```